# How to fix netlogo 6.1.1 nothing named ? has been defined

Tags: netlogo

I just started to learn Netlogo. I followed the code written by *Lynne Hamill and Nigel Gilbert*
when I finished, it reminded me that "nothing named ? has been defined".

```
foreach xs [
    create-traders 1 [ 
      set shape "house"
      setxy ? 0
      set color red
      ; give each trader some knids of produce to sell
      set stock n-of n-items-stocked fruit-and-veg
    ]
  ]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to update the code for NetLogo 6.0+ http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/transition.html#tasks-replaced-by-anonymous-procedures

Answer (score 2):

As Jasper notes in the comments, the ? is outdated syntax. Something like this should work - instead of an implicit ?, you iterate with an explicit variable (named this-x in the example below) and use that variable name wherever relevant.

```
foreach xs [ this-x ->    ; name the variable here and add the arrow
    create-traders 1 [ 
      set shape "house"
      setxy this-x 0    ; use that variable name
      set color red
      ; give each trader some knids of produce to sell
      set stock n-of n-items-stocked fruit-and-veg
    ]
  ]
```

You can think about it as equivalent to the conceptual loop "for each item in the list, call it 'this-x' and do something (everything after ->), replacing the 'this-x' in the code with whatever item is in the list at the moment".